# How can I check if a name is already in this list?

Tags: javascript, text, filesystems, discord

All of this is being triggered with:

`if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('test')) {`

I have a .txt file to store everything with FileSystem:

`leaderboard = (fs.readFileSync('leaderboard.txt', 'utf-8'))`

I need help with checking if a name is already in that list. So if someone's name is not included in that list he should be added to the bottom with a score of 1 `1,exampleUser`If a user is already included in that list his score should be incremented and updated `2,exampleUser`

And after that the .txt should be updated with:

`fs.writeFileSync('leaderboard.txt', leaderboard, 'utf8')`

I'm trying to store all users who use "test" like this:

```
1,exampleUser1
54,exampleUser2
34,exampleUser3
4,exampleUser4
65,exampleUser5
56,exampleUser6
```

And if a new user who isn't on the list says "test" he should be added to the bottom with a score of 1 for saying "test" once. Every time someone says "test" their score should either be incremented or they should be added with a score of 1 if they're not on the list.

I'm using V11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function might solve your problem

```
function updateNameAndScore(fileData, checkingName) {
    let data = fileData.split('\n');
    let names = [];
    let scores = [];
    let leaderboard = "";
    data.forEach(d => {
        let values = d.split(",");
        names.push(values[1])
        scores.push(Number(values[0]))
    });

    if (names.includes(checkingName))
        scores[names.indexOf(checkingName)]++;
    else {
        names.push(checkingName);
        scores.push(1)
    }
    
    leaderboard += (scores[0] + ',' + names[0]);
    
    for(let i = 1; i < scores.length; i++)
        leaderboard += ('\n' + scores[i] + ',' + names[i])
    
    return leaderboard;
    
}
```

`fileData` is the data which is read using `fs` module.It will be in the form (as you described) `'1,user1\n5,user2\n2,user3'`.
While `checkingName` is the name you want to search. It will be something like `'user4'`

In this implementation, the index of any name in `names` array would be the index of score associated with that name, in the `scores` array.

Comment: It's logging the leaderboard like this: `,1,2,1,1,undefined,Orangutan,Monkey,Gorilla` instead of : `1,undefined\n2,Orangutan\n1,Monkey\n1,Gorilla`

Comment: Can you please share the statement/s that how you are logging?

Comment: I explained how I want to store it in my Question.

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully get what you want but you can try these steps:

1: You can use the find() method to get the name you are looking for and make store it in a variable.

2: Use the filter method to store the rest in a new variable

3: Then use the concat method to add either the new variable you found in step 1 or else just add one 1 if the name already exists.

Eg:
const changes = 1 ? 2.concat(1) : 2.filter(exist=> exist.votes += 1)